# Count between indexes of a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.7

I am writing a function that contains a list of numbers, and I need to find a way to count the occurrences of the numbers 1 and 2, only for the last 3 values of the list.

I obviously know of the `.count()` function, but I'm wondering if there's a way to use that only between a given index, in this case that index would be `((len(history-3), (len(history))`, `history` being a list containing only values `1` and `2`.

**TL;DR:** What is a way to count occurrences of values in a list between given indexes.

Comment: `list[-3:]` will give you the last 3 element of `list`

Answer (score 2):

As Rocky Li suggest you can get the last three elements of a list by slicing it `history[-3:]`. You can then use the count function on the slice to get the count of `1` and `2` in the last three spots in the list.

For example:

```
>>> history = [1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1]
>>> count_1 = history[-3:].count(1)
>>> count_2 = history[-3:].count(2)
>>> count_1
2
>>> count_2
1
```

Answer (score 1):

Use negative slicing to get last `n` values and count using `count()`.

```
lst[-3:].count(2) # counts number of 2 from last three elements of list lst.
lst[-3:].count(1) # counts number of 1 from last three elements of list lst.
```

List has in-built `count` method for counting values.

Answer (score 0):

You could slice the list and then count

```
arr = [2,1,3,3]
arr[-3:].count(3) # 2
```

And you could do exactly the same with indices as indicated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/509295/1232796)

```
arr[start:stop].count(3)  # items start through stop-1
arr[start:].count(3)      # items start through the rest of the array
arr[:stop].count(3)       # items from the beginning through stop-1
arr[:].count(3)           # a copy of the whole array
```

I hope this is of any use.